# C# LINQ: Can we return same instance from GroupBy instead of doing new?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection where I need to group and find max from that group. So I did

```
var foo = foobar.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(x => new Foo { Name = x.Key, Version = x.Max(v => v.Version)))
                .ToList();
```

If there are say more that 2 properties, is it possible to return same object instead of creating new?

Comment: Sounds like you want [`MaxBy`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) or `x => x.OrderByDescending(v => v.Version).First()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, use `OrderByDescending` on the group and then `First` to get the max-version-object:

```
var maxVersionObjectByName = foobar
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).First())
    .ToList();
```